# How could I restore dataTables order from stateSaveCallback with stateLoadCallback?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

How could I restore dataTables order from stateSaveCallback with stateLoadCallback? (https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback)

My jsonObject from "backup":

```
{"time":"1495713075727","start":"0","length":"10","order":[["8","asc"]],"search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"},"columns":[{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}}]}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//...
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "fixedHeader": {header:true, headerOffset:34},
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 15, 20, 25], [10, 15, 20, 25]],
    "autoWidth": true,
    "dom": '<"filter"f><"dtToolbar"B>rtilp',
    "select": 'single',//true
    "responsive": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            "url": "/user_dtable_states/get_dtable_state/" + this.attr("id"),
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                callback(json);
            }
        });
    },
    "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
        $.ajax({
            "url": "/user_dtable_states/save_dtable_state/" + this.attr("id"),
            "data": data,
            "dataType": "json",
            "type": "POST",
            "success": function () {}
        });
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "language": {
    select: {
            rows: {
                _: "(%d sor kijelölve)",
                0: ""
            }
        }
    }
});
//...
});
```

The data table is working, and the order is saving, but the restore from the save not working. What is wrong? Or can you show a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
"stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
        $.ajax({
            "url": "/user_dtable_states/get_dtable_state/" + this.attr("id"),
            "data": {state: JSON.stringify(data)},
            "dataType": "json",
            "type": "POST",
            "success": function () {}
        });
    },
```

Comment: Your code shows the stateSaveCallback, but the url specifies get, not save, like your original code. I believe this is the stateLoadCallback for anyone who is confused.